# SSH to a server, run if and for loops, with write to local files within the loops

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to write a shell script that ssh's to another server to grep different files and then write the grep output to a local server.

What works for now is:

```
for X in file1 file2 file3 
touch $log
do
ssh $SERVER "grep "${X}" server_file" >> $log
done
```

Speedwise, there's no major slowdowns since my servers are quite well connected to each other. The code also looks like it could be optimised to do the ssh just once, hopefully. Ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
for X in file1 file2 file3 
touch $log
do
ssh $SERVER "grep "${X}" server_file >> $log

#While in the server, grep files then write to a local log

if ["${X}"=file1]; then
grep variable1 "${X}" >> $log
break
fi

if ["${X}"=file2]; then
grep variable2 "${X}" >> $log
break
fi
done"
```

I know it might be recommended that I push all my commands to a local.sh file then pipe it into the SSH, and if needed I can analyse the script on the other server as well.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Please explain what you intend to do. Your first script searches for the three patterns `file1`, `file2` and `file3` in the same file `serverfile` on your remote system and puts the output into the local file `$log`. According to your second script you seem to want to search for pattern `variable1` in file `file1` and search for pattern `variable2` in file `file2` on your remote server and put the output into the file `$log` on the remote server. Please [edit] your question and tell us which patterns and which local/remote files you want to use as input and output.